# Rubymotion - Ending Dispatch::Queue

Tags: ios, ruby, queue, barcode, rubymotion

I'm new to the whole iOS development both objective-c and rubymotion. So this may be a dumb question.

I'm trying to read a barcode from the camera and I can get it to read using AVCaptureMetadataOutput

So I have the following code:

```
@queue = Dispatch::Queue.new('com.scanner.app')
@output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput.alloc.init
@output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate self, queue: @queue.dispatch_object
```

Then the following method gets called.

```
def captureOutput(captureOutput, didOutputMetadataObjects: metadataObjects, fromConnection: connection)

@queue.async do
    NSLog("#{metadataObjects[0].stringValue}")
end
```

Once I receive the barcode how could I exit this queue and continue execution of the program? I know this is some advanced stuff I've literally only been using this 2 days need to mock something together quick time.

I'm not even sure if this is the correct way about reading a barcode from the camera.

This controller is triggered when a user taps a button navigation controller loads it up with the following.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(ScannerController.alloc.init, animated: true)
```

So would I be able to return back once I have found a barcode? If someone could point me in th e right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Scanning Barcodes with iOS 7 (Objective-C) http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx

Comment: Cheers for this buddy I'll have a look.. Although I have no idea how to program objective c Ill try and decipher cant be that hard :P

Comment: You are welcome.  He has downloadable source as well.  It just might be what you need.

Comment: Dispatch::Queue.main grabs the main queue where UI updates and everything happens. You can call `async` on it as well. Calling async on a queue will allow execution to continue anyway. I covered this in episode 15 of motioninmotion (sorry for the plug but it's helpful).

Comment: Do you think your video will help? If so I'll sign up. I managed to translate what Frank sent me to Ruby but I can't seem to do anything else I get weird errors when I change to another view.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it will the following code:

```
Dispatch::Queue.main.async do
  if metadataObjects.any?
    self.barcode = metadataObjects[0].stringValue
    @queue.suspend!

    process_barcode

  end
  true
end
```

Might not be the best way but works.